# Is using a HashMap the simplest solution for storing an Object that has an ID?

Tags: java

I have a class in some code, `ChatChannel` (some unneccessary code omitted), that I'm having a bit of trouble with.

```
public class ChatChannel {

    private static HashMap<String, ChatChannel> registeredChannels = new HashMap<>(); // ChannelID, ChatChannel Object

    public static void registerChannel(ChatChannel channel) {
        registeredChannels.put(channel.getId(), channel);
    }

    public static ChatChannel getChannelById(String id) {
        return registeredChannels.getOrDefault(id, null);
    }

    /** The actual ChatChannel item is defined BELOW THIS LINE **/

    private String name;
    private String id;

    public ChatChannel(String name, String id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Essentially, this class will allow me to separate messages sent by users into "channels." Users may only receive messages in joined channels, and may only send a message to their active channel. Channels should be accessible using their ID (for example, `global`).

However, my problem is I don't know whether I should use a `HashMap` or `Collection` in order to keep the code light and simple. Ideally, I'd like to be able to reference any `ChatChannel` by its `id` at any point in the code, so I don't need to constantly pass around these `ChatChannels`. What, if any, would the performance gain of using `HashMap` (and external IDs) be? Would it be roughly equal to using a Collection and then iterating through it using my `getId()` method? If so, which is considered "proper" Java?

Comment: it looks like `getChannelByObject` does not return value, is it correct?

Comment: `Map` and `Collection` do different things. Use the one that matches your data model. Note that passing a `ChatChannel` by reference is actually *cheaper* than passing the ID and performing a lookup as well as much more transparent from an API perspective.

Comment: Hard to see when you're even asking. `HashMap` is *O(1)*, iterating is *O(N)*. It is also impossible to see the point of a method that accepts and returns the same object. You need to think this through more clearly.

Comment: @Lashane Thanks for catching that, code fixed to reflect.

Comment: you've changed code, ok, now `getChannelByObject` returns... the same object as passed in, why do you need it?

Comment: @Lashane Because I'm not the best at Java, and I was considering the case of creating an equivalent ChatChannel instance elsewhere and then linking them together.

Comment: You could use a [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) instead, and then override `equals` and `hashCode` in `ChatChannel`.

Comment: Though, I do agree it is extremely unnecessary now that I actually think about it, so it's been nuked.

Comment: `getChannelById(String)` does lend itself to using a `Map<String, ChatChannel>` for retrieval given an Id. Note `private static HashMap<String, ChatChannel> registeredChannels;` _declares_ registeredChannels but does not allocate an actual map - you will get a NullPointerException when you try to store something in it. Generally, don't expose your choice of implementation; declare with the interface and allocate with a specific implementation: `private static Map<String, ChatChannel> registeredChannels = new HashMap<>();` ... also, you `.put(K, V)` into a Map, not `.add()`

Comment: @StephenP Yeah, I think it would have been a better idea to copy code from my IDE instead of stripping down a version in here. I'll put those fixes here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the stated question **"Should I be using a HashMap or Collection for performance?"** — you can't and won't use a "Collection" in this sense because a Collection is an abstract concept, represented in Java as an *interface*.

A Collection could be a List, or a Map, or a Set, among other things. You can write a method that, for example, *accepts* (any kind of) a Collection and performs an operation on everything in the Collection, but in your case here you *must* decide on what *kind* of collection to use in your implementation.

Since you're retrieving a channel given an identifier String, a Map is a useful choice because it is a key-to-value mapping; you don't have to iterate through it to find the element that has the desired key.

You should generally *declare* things generically, then *instantiate* them with a specific implementation. That is, when working with it in your code you don't care what sort of Map it is, just that it's a Map.  The actual map that you *allocate* could be a `HashMap` or a `LinkedHashMap` or a `TreeMap` — since maintaining the insertion order or keeping things sorted doesn't seem to matter here, the plain `HashMap` appears appropriate.

```
private static Map<String, ChatChannel> registeredChannels = new HashMap<>();
//             ^^^ generic declarat   |  specific implementation ^^^^
```

You might also know something about how many channels there are likely to be, or at least the size of the starting set of channels, so you may also consider the `initialCapacity` and the `loadFactor` parameters to the constructor, for example

```
// Allocate with room for 10 initial channels, expand the map size when 75% full
private static Map<String, ChatChannel> registeredChannels =
        new HashMap<>(10, 0.75);
```

Comment: Now that I actually sit down and think about this problem, this does seem to be the only valid solution. +25 to you, and thanks for letting me learn!

Answer (score 0):

It is quite likely you have IDs from a continuous range.. like 1,2,3,4... or 110,111,112,113,114... with maybe some holes. It then becomes easy to hash such sequences to a sequence like 0,1,2,3,4.... . 
Now you can use a pure array(!) which is super fast. The numbers 0..n map to index in array and access cannot be faster. The index contains pointer to the session data.
Basically an array is a map. Key is index number, and value is what it contains or points to.

Comment: Re-read the question. The IDs are _Strings_ such as "global" (given as an example in the question) so there is no continuous range of numbers and an array would have to be searched linearly to find the entry with the matching ID. Also, translating a sequence such as `110,111,112...` to `0,1,2...` is not _"[hashing](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)"_.

Comment: pedantic ehh? If I use a modulus function like x%110, it is indeed hashing. Also, it is possible to map strings to numbers which denote position on array .. v trivial